# Missing architecture. Apps built with Watch OS 5.0 and later SDKs must contain additional architectures

Tags: deployment, xcode10.1, watchos-5

[ERROR ITMS-90733](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR7dY.png)

The WatchApp target is using “armv7k” under valid architectures; and the WatchApp Extension is using both “armv7k” and “i386” under valid architectures.

When I build and try to deploy and build to the AppStoreConnect, I get the error message attached in this post.

I tried several combinations of arm64_32, armv7, and armv64 but no luck! Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have the same issue. @mhamdouchi have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet. I found a workaround for the moment. I use Xcode 10.1 for development because of the dark mode and few other features. And I use Xcode 9.4.1 for deployment using fastlane commands. I’m hoping that Apple come up with a solution in the next Xcode version!!! I’ll let you know if I find a solution before then.

Answer (score 1):

try add arm64_32 architecture in your watch extension build setting, not watch .

Comment: I tried adding arm6_32 to Watch extension under build settings, but I am still getting the same error message!

Comment: Do the valid architectures need to be ordered in a certain way? What I have at the moment is: armv7k, i386, arm6_32

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by switching the Build System setting from Legacy to "New Build System". You can find it by clicking File -> Workspace Settings of the Xcode.

Also you have to make sure that the Valid Architectures and Architectures settings were set to default values (just navigate to each and press backspace).

Comment: I did switch back to “New Build System”, and defaulted all my Valid Architecture using backspace. Now, I have a new error related to AdobeMobileLibrary: 

ld: warning: ignoring file .../AdobeMobileLibrary_Watch.a, missing required architecture arm64_32 in file .../AdobeMobileLibrary_Watch.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64_32:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBMobile", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WatchStore.o
      objc-class-ref in ExtensionDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SharedStore.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64_32

Comment: Do you use AdobeMobileLibrary in your WatchApp Extension? Just navigate to WatchApp Extension target, then Build Settings and look for the Other Linker Flags field. Remove all unnecessary libs from the field.

Comment: I had to remove a lib from Library Search Paths, it solved the error

Answer (score -1):

So I solved the problem by updating the AdobeMobileLibrary. Here is the link to files: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/mobile-services/releases